# Unable to get the return value of a bash function

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to run a script where I want bash to run a particular number of curl statements each instance.
Unfortunately I am not sure how to get the local variable I am using to count the number of curls to be returned from the function that is running the curls.

Here's my code:

```
function pusher()
{
local lines="$@"
local pushcount=0
for line in  $lines; do

    if validnumber $line; then
        #printf "$line is a valid number.\n"
        if grep -Fxq $line  results.txt; then
            echo "$line previously successfully treated." >> failures.txt
            break
        fi
        #pushing
        if is_a_personal personals ${line:0:6}; then
            /usr/bin/curl -s -k "https://192.168.2.123:567/pull?service=abc.ABCDEoboe&person=$line" > /dev/null &
            echo "$line is treated" >> results.txt
            (( pushcount++ ))
        else
            #printf "$line is not an personal number. Using others push\n"
            /usr/bin/curl -s -k "https://192.168.2.123:567/pull?service=abc.ABCDE&person=$line" > /dev/null &
            echo "$line is treated" >> results.txt
            (( pushcount++ ))
        fi

    else
        #printf "$line is NOT properly formatted or invalid.\n"
        echo "$line is NOT properly formatted or invalid." >> failures.txt
        (( pushcount++ ))
    fi


done &
echo "$pushcount"
#return $pushcount
 wait
}

xargs -L 100 -a $numberfile | while read line 
 do
    #pusher  $line
    (( count++))
    printf "$(pusher $line) messages sent using loop $count in `date +%S` seconds\n"
done
```

When I run the script, I get "0" or null instead of the value at pushcount which I am looking for.

```
0 messages sent using loop 225 in 01 seconds
0 messages sent using loop 226 in 14 seconds
0 messages sent using loop 227 in 33 seconds
0 messages sent using loop 228 in 46 seconds
```

Please what am  I doing wrong and how can I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: remove the `&` after `done` and see if that doesn't help. You need to wait for all of that code to execute for it to have a `pushcount` to have a value. Good luck.